# Laravel - How can I accomplish this dynamic routing?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to have a dynamic route like: domain.com/user, where {user} is the user ID (eg. domain.com/12345).

At the same time, I should also be able to set domain.com/about or domain.com/contact, and so on.

Is this possible with Laravel? If yes, can someone please describe how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

maintain the order:

```
Route::get('about', function(){});
Route::get('contact', function(){});
Route::get('{user}', function(){});

Route::pattern('user', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

```
Route::get('about', 'YourAboutController@method');
Route::get('contact', 'YourContactController@method');
Route::get('{userid}', 'YourUserController@method');
```

You could even go as far as to specify what `userid` should be, i.e. a number

```
Route::get('{userid}', 'YourUserController@method')->where('userid', '[0-9]+');
```